# 301 redirects how to phrase 'anything else'

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

How do I phrase a 301 redirect that is effectively 'anything else'? In other words I have a specific list of pages to redirect but I simply want anything that is not specifically redirected to go to the home page

Comment: Request you to kindly do add your tried .htaccess rules file and your samples of link eg: from where to where you want to redirect etc. That will help us to understand your question better, cheers.

Comment: You simply add a last "catch all" rule without conditions. It catches all that has not yet been rewritten. That works because rules are evaluated from top to bottom, one after another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$` stops the infinite redirect loop from root to root.

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^pag1.html$ /new_pag1.html
RedirectMatch 301 ^pag2.html$ /new_pag2.html

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/pag1.html$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/new_pag1.html$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/pag2.html$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/new_pag2.html$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ / [R=301,L]
```

Comment: and then to redirect `pag1.html` to `newpag1.html` ? Do I just list these afterwards? And does this technique still apply for several 100s of individual page redirects?

Comment: I have updated the answer with: redirecting pag1.html to new_pag1.html, pag2.html to new_pag2.html. You can do it for several 100s, but it's easier to do it from code if everything runs through index.php (if you use PHP)